# libnvidia-egl-wayland1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia

as far as I know, for correct usage of OpenGL on Ubuntu with wayland I need

libnvidia-egl-wayland1

But the package seems not to be able for 18.04. Are there other ways to obtain it?

Regards

Comment: Not available for 18.04 and be aware this is (very) experimental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install this package [from Mir PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emir-team/+archive/ubuntu/dev?field.series_filter=bionic) using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mir-team/dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-egl-wayland1
```

To revert this change use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mir-team/dev
```

Comment: Excellent, now glxinfo and vulkaninfo work again.

Comment: I was wrong regarding glxinfo, but the packages was installed.

Comment: On Ubuntu 21.10 this is not available for me as `... Has no installation candidate`

Comment: It is in universe pocket, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libnvidia-egl-wayland1 .